# Parsing bad Json Google Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

im trying to figure out how to get out "oid" value from json response, but now im have no idea, this is my first time with google script.
This is oryginal json parsed response:

```
{btcs=0.01000000, orders=[{amount=0.10000000, price=2000.00000000, oid=592589, type=1}], plns=0.00440603}
```

when im trying to get oid directly from this i got empty variable, if i parse this with "orders"

```
   oid = raw_data["orders"]; 
   oid = JSON.stringify(oid)
   oid = oid.toString().replace("[", "");
   oid = oid.toString().replace("]", "");
```

i got

```
{"oid":"592589","type":1,"amount":"0.10000000","price":"2000.00000000"},
```

If i add

```
oid = oid["oid"];
```

to my parsed "orders" it's still empty, and i tried to get out oid directly from parsed "orders" without replacing "[" and "]"but oid variable was still empty.

Comment: `var oid = raw_data.orders[0].oid;`

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, could you up-vote my answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly access the array element:

```
var oid = raw_data.orders[0].oid;
```